# Error while updating property 'placeholder' in shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I'm using react-native in my application and I see an hight levels of crash only on Android and only in production. I was not able to reproduce it and from the logs seems that this issue in on a screen that does not have any text input.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'placeholder' in shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:123)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:161)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:65)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:320)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:250)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:469)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)

Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$StringPropSetter.getValueOrDefault(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:261)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:108)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:161)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:65)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:320)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:250)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:469)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

I'm using React-native 0.62.2

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with this: Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Some float value is being passed as string

Comment: mmm... but this is not systematic and happen only in production